# Converting String to Integer: Invalid Format

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, integer, type-conversion

I'm working on an application and am reading one line from a text file to a String. Then, I convert that String to an Integer by using CInt(String). However, I get an error saying

```
Conversion from  to type Integer is not valid
```

(I've translated this, so the error output might not be exactly the same). What confuses me is that between "from" and "to", there are two blank spaces, as if the String doesn't have a name. But when I do "MsgBox(String)", it does tell me the value of it. `Integer.Parse()` didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
Dim ulistreader As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("tmp\user.list")
Dim userList As String = ulistreader.ReadLine
If userList = "-1" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox(userList) 'Output is 0
Dim UListInt As Integer = Integer.Parse(userList) 'This is where I get the error. Tried CInt(userList), didn't work
```

The code worked just fine until today. I've just started the .exe I've made a few days ago, and now it suddenly doesn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the output is *only* `0`? Could there be some other characters there, like a line feed?

Comment: I checked the length of `userList`, it's `1`. Also I did `Trim` userList, didn't fix it either.

Comment: Well then this is not reproducible im afraid (http://rextester.com/AZSTID46498)

Comment: Can you get it to output the ASCII value of your first character of your string? It's possible that you've got a non-visible prefix.

Comment: First character's ASCII value is 48. What I don't understand is that the application worked just fine until today. I haven't even touched the .exe, I've just started it, and that one .exe worked fine yesterday. Now it suddenly doesn't.

Comment: `(I've translated this, so the error output might not be exactly the same)` - I wonder if something was missed in the translation. What was the original message?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce using the values specified:

```
    Dim userList As String = "0"
    Dim UListInt As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(userList, UListInt) Then
        'conversion failed
        Stop
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(UListInt.ToString)
```

Could not reproduce. So tried this which did not fail because newline is white space at end.

```
    Dim userList As String = "0" & ControlChars.CrLf
    Dim UListInt As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(userList, UListInt) Then
        'conversion failed
        For Each c As Char In userList
            Debug.WriteLine(AscW(c))
        Next
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(UListInt.ToString)
```

And finally a failure with this

```
    Dim userList As String = "o" & ControlChars.CrLf
    Dim UListInt As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(userList, UListInt) Then
        'conversion failed
        For Each c As Char In userList
            Debug.WriteLine(AscW(c))
        Next
    End If
```